# HTML5 Throwing Two errors

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm trying to get this code to work correctly for a school project, these two lines keeps throwing an error i can seem to get fixed. The first one is linked to a drop down menu i made with JavaScript, and it works fine.

```
<li id="select"><label for="aptType">Type:</label>
```

This is the error I'm getting...
I was reading on here that i need to have id="" and that was the reason for the error, but i have id in both lines.

Error: The for attribute of the label element must refer to a form control.
From line 33, column 10; to line 33, column 45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have given wrong id for textarea please check it once again.
it should be like this.

```
<li id="select"><label for="select">Type:</label>    

<li><label for="comments">Additional Comments:</label><textarea id="comments"></textarea>
```

insted of "commments" it should be like "comments".

Comment: where can you see the html for this and where are the line no's.

Comment: question has been edited, before it was there.

Comment: yea i seen as soon as i posted there was an extra "m" in that word, been staring at that for like 10 min. Didnt have a chance to take it down quick enough. ;)